# Why would shifting from Drive to Park wake up the engine?

Tags: honda

I’m driving 2020 Odyssey in green mode, so the engine shuts off in Drive whenever you are stopped and idle for a while, e.g. waiting for green. I noticed an oddity with that feature: switching from D to P consistently wakes up the sleeping engine, with no other actions such as relaxing the brakes, only switching from D to P. I tried that a dozen times, with AC off, with the brake pedal kept pressed in P exactly as it was in D, and the same things always happens: switching from sleeping D to P audibly wakes the engine up.

I cannot think of a logical reason why a car stopped in P would require the engine to run when the same car shuts it off when stopped in D. Is this a bug in Odyssey’s logic that controls tge engine, or there is a reason for that?

Comment: Perhaps because that involves shifting thru neutral and reverse? The logic in the stop/start system on my Skoda is so erratic I have permanently disabled it (for safety: the unexpected engine cut means I can lose the power steering mid-manoeuvre).

Comment: Presumably the engine will always run in P whether the brakes are pressed or not.

Comment: @WeatherVane, Not on Odyssey: D and P (as well as R and N) are buttons that you press.

Comment: @HandyHowie, But for what purpose? Why would one need power in P when you don't need it in D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple answer is, the stop/start feature *only works in Drive*. If in any other gear, it will not engage. Put another way, since you are no longer in drive, the start/stop feature will *disengage* thus starting the engine. When you shift it out of drive for any other gear or park, it will start the engine. Since start/stop only engages in Drive, you cannot test it from any other gear. Start/stop doesn't engage in park. If you haven't shut the engine off, the vehicle thinks the engine should still be running, therefore fires it up when you shift into Park.

Comment: Sounds like a bug 8n that feature: if the goal to conserve gas the engine should certainly be stopped in Park.

Comment: @Michael - Look at it how you like. This is how it was designed to work. Not a bug. A feature. Not all features make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can't go from D to P; you need to go through N and R first. In R, it would be expected that you'd drive pretty soon afterwards. It does the same on my hyundai.

Comment: Not on Odyssey: D and P (as well as R and N) are buttons that you press.